# etoolbox error in running template for ScienceAsia

Tags: etoolbox

Currently I am using pctexv6, and I tried to typeset this following simple template for a specific journal. However the output didn't come out and I got error message saying ! Package etoolbox Error: Not running under e-TeX.

```
%
\documentclass[onecolumn,submit]{scias} 
\FrontMatterExtraVskip{0.0pt}
\title{ }
\author{ } 
\address{}
\ead{} 
\abstract{  }
\keywords{  }
\MSC{  }
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\section{Introduction}
\acknowledgements{  } 
\begin{thebibliography}{13}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I also run the same template using BakomaTex Word, and I managed to get the output. I need the output using pctexv6 so I can easily share with friends who don't have BakomaTex.

Comment: Just for fun can you post the log file (there are some interesting information at the start of that file).

Comment: You used the wrong executable to compile your file. e-TeX is an extension built into the different executables for decades now, but somehow you managed to use an executable that doesn't include this extension. Please use `pdflatex <filename>` in the console.

Comment: @daleif  

BakomaTex log file gives 
This is e-TeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6 (BaKoMa TNS 9.0)
entering extended mode
(Draft1SA.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 54 languages loaded.

Meanwhile, pctexv6 log file gives
This is pdfeTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.20a-2.2 (Web2c 7.5.3) (format=latex 2016.10.31)  4 SEP 2019 15:09
 Source specials enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**&latex Draft1SA.tex
(./Draft1SA.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>

Comment: @Skillmon Could you please instruct in detail how to use pdflatex <filename>, silly me.

Comment: None of us are using pctexv6, somewhere in the interface you specify which engine to use. Figure out where that is, and use `pdflatex` not `etex` or `pdftex` etc.

Comment: `LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>` and a pdftex version 1.20a is *ancient*. You shouldn't expect any current package to run with it.

Comment: @minsat_hsn I guess that you're using Windows, in that case open an explorer, navigate to the folder your .tex file is located in, hold down the shift-key and press the secondary mouse button on an empty space inside the folder, select to open a command line in that directory, in that command line enter "`pdflatex <filename>.tex`" with `<filename>` replaced by the file name.